# while i run the command " npx playwright test --browser=firefox " following error occurred

Tags: node.js, typescript, playwright, playwright-test

while enter below command

```
npx playwright test --browser=firefox
```

this error occurs

```
Error: Cannot use --browser option when configuration file defines projects. Specify browserName in the projects instead.
at Loader._processConfigObject (D:\Playwright class\LoginTest\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\loader.js:105:69)
at Loader.loadConfigFile (D:\Playwright class\LoginTest\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\loader.js:79:16)
at Runner.loadConfigFromResolvedFile (D:\Playwright class\LoginTest\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\runner.js:198:12)
at runTests (D:\Playwright class\LoginTest\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\cli.js:171:27)
at Gi.<anonymous> (D:\Playwright class\LoginTest\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\cli.js:82:7)
```

Comment: Don't know anything about playwright, but the error message seems pretty clear to me. You probably want to comment something on that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your playwright config setup to use projects. The command you need would be something like this:

```
npx playwright test  --project=firefox
```

Just enter the name you defined in your `playwright.config.ts` for the project you want to test.